# How to access the default camera from a component?

Tags: aframe

A component I'm making needs the default camera, but `this.el.sceneEl.camera` returns `undefined`.

[Simplified example](https://codepen.io/bryik/pen/jyNBBy):

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('test', {
  init: function () {
    console.log(this.el.sceneEl.camera)
  }
});
```

How can I retrieve the camera?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Might have to wait for the camera to be set? Need to document this, but there's an event:

```
this.el.sceneEl.addEventListener('camera-set-active', function (evt) {
  console.log(evt.detail.cameraEl); 
});
```

Comment: Yep, that works! Here is the [updated CodePen](https://codepen.io/bryik/pen/apoWox).